# Trackbar not Updating Variable Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Making a program to track a simple object and want to add in trackbars to dynamically change some of the image processing variables.

Trackbars aren't updating the thresh and bwthresh variables used for image processing in the while loop. Even after moving the trackbars, printing the values of thresh and bwthresh in the loop showed they were unaffected. I've tried making them global variables but that was to no avail. It looks to me like it should work, so I'm a bit stumped here.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import argparse
import random as rng

rng.seed(12345)

capture = cv.VideoCapture(2)
cv.namedWindow('Code Test', flags=cv.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL)
cv.namedWindow('Other One')

def do_nothing(x):
    i = 0

#THRESH CALLBACK FUNCTION TAKES GRAY IMG AND THRESHOLD
def thresh_callback(val):
    threshold = val
    canny_output = cv.Canny(src_gray, threshold, threshold * 2)
    contours, _ = cv.findContours(canny_output, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours_poly = [None]*len(contours)
    boundRect = [None]*len(contours)
    centers = [None]*len(contours)
    radius = [None]*len(contours)
    for i, c in enumerate(contours):
        contours_poly[i] = cv.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
        boundRect[i] = cv.boundingRect(contours_poly[i])
        centers[i], radius[i] = cv.minEnclosingCircle(contours_poly[i])

    drawing = np.zeros((canny_output.shape[0], canny_output.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        color = (0, 255, 0)
        #cv.drawContours(drawing, contours_poly, i, color)
        cv.rectangle(drawing, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])), \
        (int(boundRect[i][0]+boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1]+boundRect[i][3])), color, 2)
        #cv.circle(drawing, (int(centers[i][0]), int(centers[i][1])), int(radius[i]), color, 2)
    cv.imshow('Code Test', drawing)

#THRESH CALLBACK FUNCTION
max_thresh = 254
thresh = 100 #CHANGE THRESHOLD HERE
bwthresh = 250

cv.createTrackbar('BW thresh:', 'Code Test', bwthresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback)
cv.createTrackbar('Canny thresh:', 'Code Test', thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback)

while True:
    material, frame = capture.read()
    print(bwthresh)
    src_gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    src_gray = cv.blur(src_gray, (15,15))
    src_gray = cv.threshold(src_gray, bwthresh, max_thresh, cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    cv.imshow('Other One', src_gray)
    thresh_callback(thresh)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('r'):
        break

capture.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please make a smaller reproduce with only the essentials. You have both a thresh and a threshold variable. You need global to update that.